# Exchange Management tools

Tags: exchange-2007

I want export/archive some mailbox on my exchange 2007 server. Then I read a little tutorial on technet that use export-mailbox cmdlet. But it says I need of Exchange Management tools installed on a 32 bit pc.
Then I downloaded 1,2 GB of file, but after run it I see that it is an Exchange Server installation.
Then I don't understand.. I need to install an exchange instance just for export a mailbox ?
thank you very much.

Comment: Cole is correct, thankfully the "New-MailboxExportRequest" is now around in Exch2010 to do away with this cmdlet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to download the Exchange 2007 Management Tools (32 bit) from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11876) depending on your service pack level on Exchange. (Which is the full Exchange installer - see steps below)

Once downloaded, run setup.exe and do steps 1-3:

4. Install Microsoft Exchange. Setup copies the setup files locally to the computer on which you are installing Exchange 2007
5. In the Exchange Server 2007 Setup wizard, on the Introduction page, click Next.
6. On the License Agreement page, click I Accept the terms in the license agreement, and then click Next.
7. On the Error Reporting page, click Yes or No, and then click Next.
8. On the Installation Type page, click Custom Exchange Server Installation. If you want to change the path for the Exchange 2007 installation, click Browse, locate the appropriate folder in the folder tree, and then click OK. Click Next.
   [image]
9. On the Server Role Selection page, select Management Tools.
   [image]
10. If this is the first Exchange 2007 server in your organization, on the Exchange Organization page, type a name for your Exchange 2007 organization.
    The Exchange Server organization name can contain only the following characters:
    A through Z
    a through z
    0 through 9
    Space (not leading or trailing)
    Hyphen or dash
    The organization name cannot contain more than 64 characters. The organization name cannot be blank. If the organization name contains spaces, you must enclose it in quotation marks.
11. On the Readiness Checks page, view the status to determine if the organization and server role prerequisite checks completed successfully. If they have completed successfully, click Install to install Exchange 2007.
12. On the Completion page, click Finish.

Answer (score 2):

The exchange management tools are bundled with the exchange installer.  Run the setup, and you'll get an option of what to install - uncheck everything else, just install the management tools.

Unfortunately Microsoft has an especially bad habit of not giving a separate package for things like that.  It's not uncommon to have to download a 4GB file to get one 1MB utility out of it.